# how convert uppercase node into lowercase in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

when i use user defined tags with uppercase node like "`<ABC> test  </ABC>`" in ckeditor .On  clicking source, it gets  displayed  as "`<abc> test </abc>`".please help me to get the expected output , which should be `<ABC> test </ABC>` and please guide me where the code should be modified.Thanking you

Comment: Why would this matter at all? HTML isn't even case sensitive but it's good practice to keep HTML markup lowercase.

Comment: Also, you can post-process it super easily - surely that's just trivial if you can do an ajax save.

Comment: @Nenotlep first i thank you for reply,even though i would like to get output with uppercase like "<ABC> test </ABC>" plz can u help me how to do that and where we have to change the code?

Comment: I am using XML file.Case sensitivity is a project requirement

Comment: If it's XML and that important, I would use post-processing just in case. By post-processing I mean convert <abc to <ABC after the data leaves CKEditor. Where to do post-processing depends a lot on your project. You can do it in save time in the client, but if possible I would place it in the backend where CKEditor data is received. Is that possible for you? What backend solution do you use? If not, what kind of saving method do you use?

Comment: in case , if <aBc> test </aBc> , <SomeTag> test </SomeTag>

Answer (score 0):

(Continued from comments) I propose post-processing the content and not trying to bend CKEditor to produce Case Sensitive output.

I don't know your languages or your architecture, but if you get the data from CKEditor with `getData()`, you can do something like this if you want to do the conversion in the client side:

```
// Javascript
var i = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var d = i.getData();
var correctData = d.replace(/<abc/ig, '<ABC');
```

In the backend you can do something similar

```
// C# (untested)
string result = Regex.Replace(
    htmlStringFromAJAX,
    RegEx.Escape("<abc"), 
    RegEx.Escape("<ABC"), 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

// PHP (untested)
$result = str_ireplace("<abc", "<ABC", $htmlStringFromAJAX);
```

(I hope you either have just this one abc tag or a small static amount of tags - if not, this will be a very annoying solution to maintain.)